# set or init function doesnot set "visibility" of components inside before addElement() function

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

Quite wierd bug i am experiencing with Flex 4.6, with a very simple piece of code.

```
for ( var j=0 ; j< chip_num; j++)
{

isoChip = new IsoChip();

//isoChip.type=(IsoChip.YELLOW_CHIP); //<<<<<<<<<DOESNOT WORK HERE
isoChip.scaleX = isoChip.scaleY=1//0.45 ; 
isoChip.x= i + 10 * i + 5 ;

isoChip.y= y_num;

addElement(isoChip);


isoChip.type=(IsoChip.YELLOW_CHIP);  //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<WORKS HERE ONLY

y_num = y_num - 2.5 //IsoChip.height ; 

}
```

Having this component : IsoChip.mxml component

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="23" height="20" initialize="init()">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            public static const BLUE_CHIP:String = "blueChip" ;
            public static const BLACK_CHIP:String = "blackChip" ;
            public static const YELLOW_CHIP:String = "yellowChip" ;

            public function init(type_val_str="blueChip") 
            {
                blueChip.visible= false; 
                blackChip.visible =false ;
                yellowChip.visible = false ;

                //type = type_val_str  ;


            }

            function set type(type_val_str:String)
            {

                switch( type_val_str)
                {
                    case  IsoChip.BLUE_CHIP:
                        trace(">",IsoChip.BLUE_CHIP)
                        blueChip.visible = true; 
                        blackChip.visible = false ; 
                        yellowChip.visible = false ; 

                    break; 

                    case  IsoChip.BLACK_CHIP:

                        trace(">",IsoChip.BLACK_CHIP)

                        blueChip.visible = false ; 
                        blackChip.visible = true ; 
                        yellowChip.visible = false ;


                    break;

                    case  IsoChip.YELLOW_CHIP:

                        trace(">",IsoChip.YELLOW_CHIP)
                        blueChip.visible = false; 
                        blackChip.visible = false ; 
                        yellowChip.visible = true; 

                    break; 


                }

            }



        ]]>
    </fx:Script>



    <s:SWFLoader id="blueChip" x="0" y="0"  width="23" height="20" source="../swf/blue-iso-chip.swf"/>
    <s:SWFLoader id="yellowChip" x="-16" y="5"  width="23" height="20" source="../swf/yellow-iso-chip.swf"/>
    <s:SWFLoader id="blackChip" x="4" y="9" width="23" height="20" source="../swf/black-iso-chip.swf"/>
</s:Group>
```

Is it really a bug. Or am i doing something wrong ??

Comment: Makes sense, since `initialize()` is only called when the component is - well - initialized; the `initialize()` method is not the constructor. That said, I agree with @max's suggestion on using States.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using states here instead of visibility.

So, declare 3 states in your group:

```
<s:states>
    <s:State name="blue" />
    <s:State name="black" />
    <s:State name="yellow" />
</s:states>
```

Then apply each state for each SWFLoader:

```
<s:SWFLoader id="blueChip" includeIn="blue" ... />
<s:SWFLoader id="blackChip" includeIn="black" ... />
<s:SWFLoader id="yellowChip" includeIn="yellow" ... />
```

And at last, in the ActionScript code change the state based on the condition:

```
switch( type_val_str) {
    case  IsoChip.BLUE_CHIP:
        currentState = "blue";
    break; 

    case  IsoChip.BLACK_CHIP:
        currentState = "black";
    break;

    case  IsoChip.YELLOW_CHIP:
        currentState = "yellow";
    break; 
}
```